# How to take a log of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, logging

I am using matplot lib and python to plot plots.
I have a plot with an x-list and a y-list. The plot is currently taking the absolute values of the y values and integrating them, using the following code.

```
count = 0
for x in range(10):
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
             if featureCount < numLabels:
                 ax = plt.subplot2grid((5,5), (i,j))
                 y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(labelList[count],timeList, initial=0)
                 ax.plot(timeList,y_int)
                 ax.set_title(str(count))
                 count+=1
```

I would now like to also take the log(base 10) of the graph in order to straighten out the curve. How would I do this? I am having trouble since labelList[count] is also list. Once I do this, I would like to change labelList[count] to be the updated, log of the integrated data. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `ax.semilogy(timeList, y_int)`

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys Thank you! Where should this line be inserted, or what should it replace?

Comment: The statement `ax.set_yscale('log')` will set the y-axis to log-scale, is that what you want to do?

Comment: @BramDekker I don't want to change the axis, but to take the log of the data

Comment: @emily123 okay, you can just take the logarithm of all elements in the y_int array. So after `y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(labelList[count],timeList, initial=0)` you put `y_int = [math.log(y,10) for y in y_int]`. On top of the file you have to import the math module: `import math`